# How to hide description on categories and tags?

Tags: categories, description

Does anybody know how I can hide the descriptions from view for the categories and tags for my website? I have searched for a while but can't find any solutions. I would like it so that when they are clicked it just shows the categories or posts available, no description visible. Can someone show me how to do this please?

https://lawlessons.co.uk/ (when hovering the mouse over the category it brings up a description).

https://lawlessons.co.uk/tag/contract-law-agreement-offer-and-acceptance (when opening a category it shows a description).

https://lawlessons.co.uk/category/contract-law/agreement-offer-and-acceptance (when opening a tag it shows a description).

(Author wordpress theme).

Happy new year!

Comment: do you need the description elsewhere? if not, you could simply go into the category and delete the description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no description disabled in the theme settings, then you will have to edit the template files. This description is displayed in the title tag of the link, and you need to look for the [category_description ()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/category_description/) function in the files. If you find it, you can just comment it out.